In Flutter, can I schedule exact alarms with some background task?
I'm making an alarm clock Flutter application with an extra function. I want to download an image from my server right before alarm goes off and show that image with ringing sound. So, I need to execute a background download process on the exact time. Because of extra functions, I can't download image early with job scheduling packages.
I already made same Android native app using Foreground Service and AlarmManager and now I'm remaking  it to Flutter application because I want to support iOS also.
I tried it with 4 packages(workmanager, flutter_local_notifications, awesome_notifications, alarm) but I couldn't make it.

With workmanager, when the device is in doze mode, os decide timing for executing work so it can't be an alarm clock.

With flutter_local_notifications, awesome_notifications, alarm, there is no listener API I can start my background service because iOS policy that doesn't allow to trigger background process when the app is not foreground, I guess.

Cause I want support iOS also, I've never tried android_alarm_manager_plus package.


I couldn't find any other way to make my simple alarm clock that just download only 1 file. I don't want to make iOS native code and use method channel because my skill's only for Android. Is there any other way? Thank you for reading my saga!

Is this solved? I'm also looking for the answer.

@ryanhuang1124 Unfortunately no..
